# ffmpeg drawtext filter problem with eif option

Tags: ffmpeg

I want a countdown timer in my video in hours minute second format. I tried "drawtext" filter using eif option but it only provides me with countdown timer in seconds. I want complete H:M:S format.

**Edit:**

Currently I'm using

```
ffmpeg -i input_file -vf drawtext=fontfile=/address:text='%{eif:10-t:d}'
```

This will start countdown from 10 seconds

Comment: What's the current command you're using?

Comment: currently i m using ffmpeg -i input_file -vf drawtext=fontfile=/address:text='%{eif\:10-t\:d}'
this will start countdown from 10 seconds